# How to detect gates objects from by Edge Detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I want to detect this gate from the video in real time. I can detect the edge. There are gates of other colours too. Can anyone suggest me how to detect the gate from here?

[image]

Comment: Please, consider taking some time to read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: Start by trying to write some code based, for example, on code you might find using a popular search engine using well- (or even not-so-well-) crafted search terms. If despite your best efforts to debug and understand why your code doesn’t wrk then POST YOUR CODE on here as a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could try to use a MedianBlur to get rid of the squared edges from the floor.
2. Then transform the image to the HSV space and use the saturation or hue channel to get a grayscale image. This helps to create contrast between the colored gate and the dark line on the floor as well as the water. When the other gates have colors other than blue, the hue channel should work fine. Given the blurred grayscale image, your edge detection could work much better.

Hope this helps you a bit

Comment: This is about the right level for the question: OP didn’t provide code so you didn’t respond with code. Well done. Asking for code solutions without providing any evidence of attempt to code a solution, or even attempts to research a solution is off-topic on StackOverflow.